# How can I evaluate my hosting provider's claim to be "optimized for Magento"?

Tags: php, optimization, magento, hosting

I'm currently responsible for running, modifying, and tuning a Magento installation. I'm not satisfied with our current hosting plan, and I'm looking for alternatives. I see several hosting providers that advertise that they optimize their servers for Magento (e.g. Nexcess, MageMojo), but they all seem to be short on technical details. What does one do to a server to optimize it for Magento that is different from optimizing for any other heavyweight PHP/MySQL application?

My current understanding is that because of its EAV data model and its massive XML configuration files, Magento performance is almost always I/O-bound - but my understanding is that that's true for most other PHP/MySQL applications at scale. RAM and cores are cheaper than SSD space, basically.

How can I tell whether these "optimizations" are worth the premium that Magento-oriented hosting providers charge? Is there a technical basis to the claim of "optimization" or is optimizing for Magento the same as optimizing for performance on any other PHP/MySQL application?

---

Note: since this question brushes up against the site's guidelines, let's be clear on a couple of things:

- a correct answer would say "no, Magento is not an unusual PHP/MySQL application, scaling it to 10,000 users is only trivially different from scaling Drupal, WordPress, or Joomla! to that level" or "yes, Magento has the following characteristics which require the application of non-trivial config changes, optimization techniques, or server tuning, that you would use for no other PHP/MySQL application." So there does exist a definitive correct answer to this question.
- I don't plan on actually implementing such tuning myself: if I did, I'd probably ask Server Fault. I'm asking about Magento's guts, I'm asking about *why* it performs the way it does and asking for comparisons to the internals of similar apps, so I'm asking Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'd personally expect this to mean mainly "we have all the right packages installed by default".

Comment: @ceejayoz - I'm trying not to be *that* cynical about it. Just due-diligence cynical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the normal:

- php version
- apc, caching
- Memory, cpu, disk space, bandwidth, etc.

With something like magento there are concerns of [PCI compliance](http://www.pcicomplianceguide.org/). So you need to understand the physical security of the data centers, mysql setup (make sure they are not shared sql servers), etc. It's best to get a dedicated server, or at least a vps, so that your resources/data is isolated from everyone else's which will help with security.

I have worked with some reputable Magento hosting providers, so if you have some you are checking out, let me know, and I will let you know my honest thoughts

Comment: Oh hey, I hadn't thought about PCI compliance - that *is* something unusual.

Comment: Not really unusual, when dealing with any sort of eCommerce/credit card where you are doing the actual processing with the merchant (not Paypal), you have to be PCI compliant. You could lose your merchant account, and Visa/Master/etc can precent you from using their cards which obviously is not good.

Comment: True, but at least eCommerce is a specific niche with well-defined requirements. You don't necessarily need to care about that with a large WP/Joomla/Drupal install, but you pretty much always care about it with a Magento install.

Comment: Accepting this answer because it told me more things that I didn't previously know than the other answer (upvoted both, natch).

Answer (score 2):

Magento is a cpu consuming beast that is more impacted by its internal complex multilayer object architecture (which allows very important customizations "out of" magento core code but that also implements a near full facade for Zend Framework which itself is not known for being light) + pseudo orm collection code that is really suboptimal than its underlying complex but not that bad EAV DB model.

So , a good way to optimize magento for a hoster is to provide :

- A PHP bytecode optimizer like APC (since a single call in magento can end into several tens of thousands of PHP line codes being executed)
- A memcached to optimize result & session storage used by magento (hopefully magento has  configuration options that enable it to take memcached as cache engine)
- Ideally a varnish full page cache proxy , but beware, this needs very tricky varnish config to have magento gracefully working.

The full page cache will really release the load on the php code execution for having page displayed.
The memcached will give fast access to last known results & session data
The bytecode optimizer will reduce the load of php code execution server side.

Then ,the DB itself has to be optimized in a more "standard" way using InnoDB settings matching CPU cores & all the other well known mysql optimizations.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen Magento plugins that connect it to memcached - that's definitely a thing that's available.

Comment: The thing is that while those are definitely good things to do for performance, those aren't unusual optimizations. If I wanted to scale up a Drupal install, for example, I'd probably want to do all of those. So what I hear you saying it just "Magento is a resource-hungry PHP application," not that it's resource-hungry in an unusual way.

Comment: What i would say is that magento cannot run with good performance on non tuned systems and is even unusable on 'low end' hosting whereas drupal can.That's where the "unusually hungry" part starts. The PHP memory requirements for a magento install are also consequent (256M is a bare minimum as soon as the catalog has several thousands of items & some additional extensions are installed).

Comment: So your perspective is that a performance-tuned LAMP stack is basically a *requirement* for Magento, but for other PHP apps, you can start with a basic LAMP install and be basically okay, adding optimizations/tweaks/tuning on an ad-hoc basis?